# Can't get started with the Hello World Electron app example

Tags: syntax-error, electron, unexpected-token

I've gone through the "Your first Electron app" and followed this and other tutorials to get started, but once I use `npm start` or `npm run start` or `electron .` I always get an error message that I can't understand.

[image: https://imgur.com/SyxJaLC]

The code I used was copied from the [Writing Your First Electron App | Electron Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app) tutorial.

I tried to run `node index.js` to maybe get a better error message, but it didn't help me.

Comment: What code do you have in vm.js around line 79?

Comment: From what I was able to figure out, vm.js is part of the node.js-engine and I could not find it. I found a vm.d-file, but it's only 64 lines long.

I also tried to find the main.js from the electron-package, but its hidden in an asar-file.

Even if I reduce the code in my index.js to `const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')` it throws the same error-message. So I guess it has something to do with how it all was installed.

Comment: we need to see your `index.js` or `main.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was an encoding-issue in the end. I created my files using TotalEdit Pro as unicode-files, but node/electron seems to want UTF-8. Now it works.